# Fastest way to get the distinction/delta between a local table and the values of a database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have the following requirements:

1. I have many different database tables for example a table which shows different materialnumbers. There are many thousands rows in the database table (>100.000)
2. A user could import data with an excel file with thousends of rows.
3. The distinction/ difference between the excel file and the database-table should be added. The allready existing materialnumbers should be updated.

Is there a faster way than this to get the allready existing values in entity framework:

```
var allreadyExistingMaterialnumbersInDatabase = myDbContext.Materialnumbers.Where(x=>myExcelListMaterialnumbers.Contains(x.Materialnumber)).ToList();
```

After that step i have to do a update for all the data which is returned in the code example and then i have to insert all the difference between the list allreadyExistingMaterialNumbersInDatabase and myExcelListMaterialnumbers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fastest would be to import the raw data into a temp table with index on Materialnumber and then analyse there. You should use a stored-procedure for this and also for the creation.

Comment: So there is no fast way to execute this in the entity framework itself? To be more clearly i have added the excel rows allready in a separate "excel import data log table".

Comment: Is there already an index on `Materialnumber`? Note that your apporach has already limitations, i think your local list can contain maximum 2100 items, since they are all passed as unique parameters to the database(`WHERE MaterialNumber IN(@p1, @p2, @p3, ..., @p2100)`). You will get an exception if it's too large.

Comment: Yes there is an index on materialnumber. In this case my local approach will not fit the requirements. I think your solution is valid and i will figure it out.